# Adding buttons to each row of a table to remove said row

Tags: javascript, html, css

just looking for a simple solution on solving this, Consider the the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Javascript - Add HTML Table Row </title>
        <meta charset="windows-1252">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <form>
        <script>
            function addRow()
            {
                // get input values
                    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
                    var currentAge = 
                document.getElementById('currentAge').value;
                    var Birthday = document.getElementById('Birthday').value;
                    var carType = document.getElementById('carType').value;
                    var Delete = document.getElementById('Delete').value;                  



                  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];


                  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length/2+1);


                  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);  
                  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  var cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
                  var cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);



                  cel1.innerHTML = name;               
                  cel2.innerHTML = currentAge;                 
                  cel3.innerHTML = Birthday;
                  cel4.innerHTML = carType;
                  cel5.innerHTML = Delete;


           function myFunction(){
           var x = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
           document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + " tr 
           elements in the table.";
            }


            </script>
            </form>
        </head>
    <style>


    table, th {

    border: 1px solid black;    
    }

    tbody td{
    padding: 30px;
    }


    tbody tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #F4BC01;
    color: #ABC412;
    }

    $("")


    </style>

    <body>
    <h2>Basic HTML table</h2> <button onclick="myFunction()">Press me for 
    elements amount</button>
    <p id ="demo"></p>


        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br/><br/>
        Age: <input type="text" name="currentAge" id="currentAge" /><br/><br/>
        Date of Birth <input type="date" name="Birthday" id="Birthday" /><br/>

        <button onclick="addRow();">Display</button><br/><br/>

        <p>Eye Colour:</p>

        <select id="carType">
        <option value="ferrari"  id="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
        <option value="lamborghini"  id="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
        <option value="porsche"  id="porsche">Porsche</option>
        <option value="bugatti"  id="bugatti">Bugatti</option>
        <option value="pagani" id="pagani">Pagani</option>

        </select>


        <table border="1" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>CarType</th>
                <th>Delete Entry
                <button id="Delete" onclick="remove_update(event)">delete</button> //this button right here but in each row and not here. should remove said row

                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

What im trying to do is within cel 5 (delete entry) is to add a delete button to each row that is entered into the table that will remove that row but don't know how to go about this. Ideally would like to do this without the use of JQuery if possible, since i've not touched upon it as of yet.

Comment: No need for jQuery if you're not already using it for something else, from `e.target` the `<tr>` you want to `.remove()` is just a few `.parentElement` away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rowIndex` property to delete the row.

```js
function addRow() {
  // get input values
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var currentAge = document.getElementById('currentAge').value;
  var Birthday = document.getElementById('Birthday').value;
  var carType = document.getElementById('carType').value;

  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  const index = table.rows.length;
  var newRow = table.insertRow(index);
  newRow.setAttribute('data-index', index);
  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
  var cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);

  cel1.textContent = name;
  cel2.textContent = currentAge;
  cel3.textContent = Birthday;
  cel4.textContent = carType;
  cel5.innerHTML = '<button onclick="removeRow(this)" type="button" class="delete-button">Delete</button>';
}


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + "tr elements in the table.";
}


function removeRow(evt) {
  const deleteIndex = evt.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(deleteIndex);
}
```

```css
table,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

tbody td {
  padding: 30px;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #F4BC01;
  color: #ABC412;
}
```

```html
<h2>Basic HTML table</h2> <button onclick="myFunction()">Press me for 
    elements amount</button>
    <p id ="demo"></p>


        Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br/><br/>
        Age: <input type="text" name="currentAge" id="currentAge" /><br/><br/>
        Date of Birth <input type="date" name="Birthday" id="Birthday" /><br/>

        <button onclick="addRow();">Display</button><br/><br/>

        <p>Eye Colour:</p>

        <select id="carType">
        <option value="ferrari"  id="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
        <option value="lamborghini"  id="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
        <option value="porsche"  id="porsche">Porsche</option>
        <option value="bugatti"  id="bugatti">Bugatti</option>
        <option value="pagani" id="pagani">Pagani</option>

        </select>


        <table border="1" id="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Birthday</th>
                <th>CarType</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should be doing is that you set the `innerHTML` of `cel5` to a button, e.g.:

```
cel5.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="delete-button">Delete</button>';
```

Then, you can simply add a click event listener on the table, and check if a click event has emitted from the button element. If it matches, you then delete the closest `<tr>` element:

```
document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Check if click event came from delete button
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('delete-button'))
    return;

  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
});
```

See proof-of-concept example below:

```js
function addRow() {
  // get input values
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var currentAge = document.getElementById('currentAge').value;
  var Birthday = document.getElementById('Birthday').value;
  var carType = document.getElementById('carType').value;

  var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
  var newRow = table.insertRow(table.rows.length / 2 + 1);

  var cel1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cel2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cel3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cel4 = newRow.insertCell(3);
  var cel5 = newRow.insertCell(4);

  cel1.innerHTML = name;
  cel2.innerHTML = currentAge;
  cel3.innerHTML = Birthday;
  cel4.innerHTML = carType;
  cel5.innerHTML = '<button type="button" class="delete-button">Delete</button>';
}


function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Found " + x + "tr elements in the table.";
}

document.getElementById('table').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Check if click event came from delete button
  if (!e.target.classList.contains('delete-button'))
    return;
    
  e.target.closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<h2>Basic HTML table</h2> <button onclick="myFunction()">Press me for 
    elements amount</button>
<p id="demo"></p>


Name: <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br/><br/> Age: <input type="text" name="currentAge" id="currentAge" /><br/><br/> Date of Birth <input type="date" name="Birthday" id="Birthday" /><br/>

<button onclick="addRow();">Display</button><br/><br/>

<p>Eye Colour:</p>

<select id="carType">
  <option value="ferrari" id="ferrari">Ferrari</option>
  <option value="lamborghini" id="lamborghini">Lamborghini</option>
  <option value="porsche" id="porsche">Porsche</option>
  <option value="bugatti" id="bugatti">Bugatti</option>
  <option value="pagani" id="pagani">Pagani</option>
</select>


<table border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Birthday</th>
    <th>CarType</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the head, **add a function** that understands rows and cells. Call some delete on a parent of a cell (Delete the `<tr>` in which the `<td>` is located at). then on the body add to each dynamic button an `onClick` event and set that function you created earlier ON.

You can use a script like this:

```
function deleteRow() {
    var tableData = event.target.parentNode; 
    var tableRow = tableData.parentNode;
    tableRow.parentNode.removeChild(tableRow);
}
```

In the button you create (dynamically or fixedly) you should add an **onClick** event. For example:

```
<tr>
    <td>John Doe</td>
    <td>$10,000</td>
    <td><input type="submit" value="Delete" id="Delete" onclick="deleteRow()"></td>
</tr>
```